# Spring and JSR303

Tags: java, bean-validation

I need to validate an XML coming from a vendor and saving it as XML type in oracle....

Now i need a process to trigger a validation engine... which is going to validate it and save the value in indicator as 'YES' or 'NO' example if the address in XML doesn't exist in our dB make the address indicator as 'NO' [which we correct in another process...]

I already used JSR303 in Spring 303,  which is very effective and easy to use....but it uses a form backing object and @valid.....

Can I use it here in my design...

Or let me put it this way -

Is it possible for Spring's JSR-303 implementation to validate object fields that are not from form input?

I know its a very vague question...so please let me know if I need to explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the work for object's validation performed by JSR-303 provider (hibernate-validator in most cases). Spring's role in this process is minimal -- it just parses user's data, binds it to the object and passes this object to validator. Also, during application startup, Spring creates `Validator` instance.

So, you can interfere in this proccess: create object, which will be validated, manually, get `Validator` instance and pass object to him. As result you will get a `Set` of `ConstraintViolation` which represents errors of each fields.

In this scheme main problem is that JSR-303 validator works with object, while you operates with XML document. You may deserialize XML document to object, validate it and, if it doesn't have errors, serialize it back to XML and writes to DB.

I recommend to read the following part of Hibernate Validator manual: [2.2. Validating constraints](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#validator-usingvalidator-validate) It describe `Validator` interface and a few useful methods: `validate()`, `validateProperty()` and `validateValue()`.

One benefit from Spring here is that you won't need to create `Validator` by yourself with `Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator()`: just `@Autowire`  it as all other Spring beans:

```
@Autowired
private Validator validator;
```

Comment: Thanks... One more Question...do you think I should use the JSR here or use the good old Spring Exception Handling.....

Comment: It depends on how many validation rules do you have. If you have a few rules better use simple validation mechanism.